# Computing the Jacobian determinant for a change of variables,

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Why do we compute the partial derivatives in terms on the new variables and not with respect to the old variables?  Can someone say this intuitively, so that I have the best chance of remembering why?

For instance, when going from x,y coordinates to, say, u,v coordinates, I am tempted to compute the "Jacobian" as the determinant of the partial derivatives $u_x, u_y, v_x, v_y$, which would be wrong, I think - and that the correct Jacobian is gotten from computing the partials $x_u, x_v, y_u, y_v$.

Thanks,

Edit: is this a good way of thinking about it (from Wikipedia): I am computing the *factor* by which x,y shrinks or expands u and v?

Answer (score 1):

Think of how it would go for a single variable

$\int f(x) dx = \int f(u) \cdot \frac{dx}{du} du$  ( you can see the $du$'s cancelling )

rather than 
$\int f(u) \cdot \frac{du}{dx} du$

The Jacobean is the factor by which the transformation from $(u,v)$ to $(x,y)$ expands or contracts areas, so that's what you need to multiply the $(u,v)$ area to recover the $(x,y)$ area, which is what the original question is asking for.

I remember when I first learned about Jacobeans I had a eureka realization about the nature of determinants, for a linear transformation the Wronskian matrix is constant and its determinant is the factor by which areas are multiplied so that a 2x2 matrix that maps the plane onto a line has determinant zero, this is why a matrix must have determinant zero in order to map any point other than $(0,0)$ onto $(0,0)$ ( because a matrix with a non-zero determinant must be one-to-one and zero always maps to zero under any linear transformation )

Edit: ( response to comment )

the short answer is that you are just conveniently taking advantage of the fact that

$$\frac{du}{dx} \frac{dx}{du}=1   $$

consider the example $f(x)=x^2$, Let $u=x^2$ so that $du = 2 x dx =2 \sqrt{u} dx$

Our Jacobean is now $\frac{dx}{du}=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{u}}$

Notice that we could has got the same Jacobean by expressing $x$ in terms of $u$ from the outset

$$x=u^\frac 12 \Rightarrow dx = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{u} } du$$

So

$$ \int x^2 dx = \int u \left( \frac{dx}{du} \right ) du = \frac 12 \int u^{\frac 12} du = \frac 13 u^\frac32 =\frac 13 x^3 $$

Comment: if I take your suggestion and just consider the simplest single variable case, say, going from the x-coordinate to the u-coordinate.  now say f(x) = x^2 + 5.  I let u = x^2 + 5.  but then to compute the "jacobian", we compute du/dx = 2x.  du = 2xdx, which shows that du/2x = dx.  so, in this simple case, 1/2x is the "Jacobian", when going from x to u.  but notice that we've differentiated with respect to the *old* variable, namely the x-coordinate... why is that? Thanks,

Comment: But if you think about it, you often do the same thing in the 1-dmensional case. In trig substitution for example you might let $x=\sin z$. Let's consider the 2-dimensional case: you have a planar region that is "hard to deal with" so you want to do your integral over an "easier one", say a rectangle. So you let $x=x(u,v)$ and $y=y(u,v)$. You will then pull back to the $u-v$ plane and do the integral there. So you need to express your integrand in terms of $u$ and $v$. The Jacobian will then of course need to be a function of $u$ and $v$.